# Using A Result Set In A MySQL Function

Tags: mysql, function, return-value, resultset

I'm trying to create a function that reads a passed variable, if the variable begins with a * then I need it to read a result set of descriptions from another table and concatenate them together and return the concatenated value as the description.  If it doesn't start with * then it needs to read the description from a different table and return that value as the description.

i.e. I have bundles of skus that contain several skus in them, so, for those, I need to read the descriptions for all of the skus in the bundles (from the bundles db table).  if it is not a bundle, then just read the description from the items table.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Posting the relevant schema will be helpful.